# UITextView's Data Detectors options and text apperance

Tags: ios, uitextview, uiappearance, nsdatadetector, datadetectortypes

UITextView provides a very useful Data Detectors functionality, that supports:

- Phone number detection
- URL detection Street address detection
- Event detection
- Shipment tracking number detection
- Flight number detection, and
- Information users may want to look up

I prepared a small sample to test it out, and I just have one question:

> How can I change the appearance of detected text?

Changes applied to `tintColor` and/or `linkTextAttributes` appears to only work for URL, email, and phone number. Changes applied to `tintColor` or `linkTextAttributes` properties of UITextView DOES NOT appear to have any effect on items like Event/ Date or Time, Address, Shipment Number, and Flight Number.

[image: UITextView's Data Detectors option sample]

Comment: You should probably file a bug about this at bugreport.apple.com. If linkTextAttributes does not apply to the new "light" links in iOS 10, there should probably be a way to customise them.

Comment: Bug filed. Reference # 29660476.

Comment: @Mustafa Where you able to solve this issue?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I filed a Bug Report with Apple, but they never responded. I guess we'll have to wait for the support. :)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be only one way using NSDataDetector.

Sample of the date detection is below.

```
let wAS = aTextView.attributedText.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString

let wDateResult = try! NSDataDetector( types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.date.rawValue ).matches(
    in: wAS.string
,   options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions( rawValue: 0 )
,   range: NSMakeRange( 0, wAS.string.characters.count )
)
for w in wDateResult {
    wAS.addAttributes( [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red ], range: w.range )
}

aTextView.attributedText = wAS
```